Excel problem with right and left function
I have data with date and time together, I was trying to separate them in a new column. When I put the formula and press enter the number came to the new column but are different. It change the number at the date and the time.
Example The formula =Right(A2,8) to get what is at the right I count everything that I need, the number are like this 02:34:54, it came back like this 75694444. The date was 2017-09-01 the formula for the date was =left(A2,10) came back 42979.00140. I did the same formula in google sheet with no problem.

Dates are stored as doubles in Excel.  So to get the date use INT:
=INT(A1)

For the time part use MOD:
=MOD(A1,1)

Then format the result cells appropriately.

Changing the Format to General exposes the double:

It is this underlying value that Excel uses and not the formatted version, unless the date is actually a text string that looks like a date.

To add to Scott's answer, RIGHT() and LEFT() are string/text manipulation functions
